# Unlock bootloader with PIN using ADB

Tags: lock-screens, boot

My phone screen has shattered, and is not at all visible. I made the mistake of rebooting the phone via ADB, and now it is stuck at the boot lockscreen.

I am interested in copying the files off the device onto my computer. The problem is, the disk is encrypted, and to decrypt, I need to enter the pin code, which requires using the screen.

How can I decrypt the disk, or unlock the boot-screen via ADB?

Within adb I attempted `cd sdcard` and it returns `/sdcard: No such file or directory`, despite `ls` showing it to exist.

- Device is not rooted.

Comment: if adb was authorized previously, you could just run [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc). but i am afraid for FDE adbd is not running this early stage.. try

Comment: What type of lock-screen are we talking about? A password prompt from a full disk encryption (after entering the password the OS starts to boot) or is it regular lock screen with a pin/password/pattern lock? For pin/password prompts you usually can connect a keyboard via USB OTG adapter (if your device supports OTG).

Comment: @Robert The former.

Comment: Wait you added something about adb. In this case it can't be the FDE prompt. Looks like your device uses File Based Encryption (you forgot to mention your device type and Android version). In any way the only option I know is the USB keyboard via USB OTG (an USB mouse would also be an option but as you don't see all of the screen...).

Comment: rebooting the phone via ADB does require authorized RSA key. scrcpy will work too